# Creating a table with dynamic data in Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database that has fields (row and col). I am now creating a dynamic table. Here is my code.

```
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= $fetch['row']) {
        echo "<tr>";
            $j = 1;
            while($j <= $fetch['col']) {
                echo "<td>";
                        echo "col ".$i." "."row".$j;
                echo "</td>";
                $j++;
            }

        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

This works fine the result of it is this.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| col 1 row 1 | col 1 row 2 | col 1 row 3 | col 1 row 4 | col 1 row 5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| col 2 row 1 | col 2 row 2 | col 2 row 3 | col 2 row 4 | col 2 row 5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| col 3 row 1 | col 3 row 2 | col 3 row 3 | col 3 row 4 | col 3 row 5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| col 4 row 1 | col 4 row 2 | col 4 row 3 | col 4 row 4 | col 4 row 5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| col 5 row 1 | col 5 row 2 | col 5 row 3 | col 5 row 4 | col 5 row 5 |
```

How do I make it like this?

```
    1 |2 |3 |4 |5
    6 |7 |8 |9 |10
    11|12|13|14|15
    16|17|18|19|20
    21|22|23|24|25
```

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: if you just want to number them in order, you can just add `$number = 1;` under the `$i = 1;` then inside your inner loop change `echo "col ".$i." "."row".$j;` to `echo $number;` and finally under `$j++;` add `$number++;`

Comment: @JapanGuy  Thank you sir...How do I put color on the specific number of <td> example I want <td> number 23 to be background color: red how do I do it?

Comment: I dont want to write the whole code for you, why dont you think about it? Look in your code: there is a line that says `echo "<td>";`

Comment: You need the <td> to have a background for 23,  like this `<td style='background: red'>`

Comment: Which means you need to replace `echo <td>;` with an if statement that shows the background coloring only when $number is 23

Answer (score 0):

This is the idea. Haven't run the code. $i is the column and $j is the row according to your output table, unlike what it says in your code.

```
echo ( ($i-1)*count($fetch['col']) ) + $j;  
// will have to switch $i, $j, $fetch['row'] if you want the output in the other order
```

> ($i-1)*count($fetch['row']) is the row offset calculation
>
> row 1: (1-1)*5 => 0 + $j
>
> row 2: (2-1)*5 => 5 + $j

Comment: Thank you sir...How do I put color on the specific number of <td> example I want <td> number 23 to be background color: red how do I do it?

Comment: You should be using css for that
$style='';
if(<condition for color>)
$style="style="background-color:red";
<td $style>

or

<td class="red">

.red{background-color:red}

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i = 1;
 echo '<table border="1">';
 echo '<tr>';
 for($i; $i<=25; $i++){
   echo '<td>';
   echo $i;
   echo '</td>';
   if($i%5 == 0){
     echo '</tr><tr>';
   }
 }
 echo '</tr>';
 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you sir...How do I put color on the specific number of <td> example I want <td> number 23 to be background color: red how do I do it?

Comment: You can put class in td's for red color and different class for other color and apply css on these classes. You can also do this through jquery.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(3)').css('background','red');
});
</script>